# iOS App Extension type confusion - to open app when user selects a particular text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-app-extension

I have a voip app that works on numbers and extensions. I want to have an app extension and the use case for my app extension is whenever user selects a text ( numbers specifically) and taps on my app extension in action menu, it would show the appropriate contact in app extension and when user taps on it, would open my voip app. I am confused between share app extension and action app extension. Which one should i choose? I am more inclined towards action app extension, but my colleague presents me with argument that share is available in menu controller. Since Apple is vigilant about extension and their purposes, any pointers would help?